# Moving average of 2 columns

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g

Hello I have a problem. I know how to calculate moving average last 3 months using oracle analytic functions... but my situatiion  is a little different

Month-----ProductType-----Sales----------Average(HAVE TO FIND THIS)

1---------A---------------10

1---------B---------------12

1---------C---------------17

2---------A---------------21

3---------C---------------2

3---------B---------------21

4---------B---------------23

5

6

7

8

9

So we have sales for each month and each product type... I need to calculate the moving average of the last 3 months and the particular product.

example:

For month 4 and Produt B it would be (21+0+12)/3

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 4):

Another option is to use the windowing clause of analytic functions

```
with my_data as (
  select 1 as month, 'A' as product, 10 as sales from dual union all
  select 1 as month, 'B' as product, 12 as sales from dual union all
  select 1 as month, 'C' as product, 17 as sales from dual union all
  select 2 as month, 'A' as product, 21 as sales from dual union all
  select 3 as month, 'C' as product, 2 as sales from dual union all
  select 3 as month, 'B' as product, 21 as sales from dual union all
  select 4 as month, 'B' as product, 23 as sales from dual 
)
select 
  month, 
  product, 
  sales,
  nvl(sum(sales) 
    over (partition by product order by month 
          range between 3 preceding and 1 preceding),0)/3 as average_sales
from my_data
order by month, product
```

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT month, 
       productType, 
       sales,
       (lag(sales, 3) over (partition by produtType order by month) +
        lag(sales, 2) over (partition by productType order by month) + 
        lag(sales, 1) over (partition by productType order by month))/3 moving_avg
  FROM your_table_name
```

-- edited to add missing right paren

Comment: Works good. But is there a way I can consider nulls to be zero? for example... when I dont have a value in one of those 3 rows can i consider that to be zero and calculate the average?

Comment: @mahen: just add an NVL to the lag phrase. either lag(NVL(sales, 0), x) or NVL(lag(sales, x), 0)

Comment: Hi but this just for 3 months. How can we calculate rolling average from beginning of months till current month?